# After we sign up online website for services, we give up our phone number and email address,legally what can the company do internally and exterally

Tags: privacy, online, online-piracy, personal-information

During the pandemic time, fond myself signup a lot of food delivery services, where pretty much they all asks my phone, email and address. And some online services Now, I got call from people trying to ask me to donate, selling me car insurance, and some "Amazon" calls saying that I made a purchase of 5 iPads, where they need to verify my personal information more than before

Although I don't "think" the companies just sell my information to scammers, I do question what can those companies can do with my personal information?

(I also think people/scammers just become more active than since they got more time now.)

Comment: It depends where you are. USA has no federal law like Europe's GDPR but some US states have an equivalent, such as California's CCPA.

Comment: Note that those calls from "Amazon" are typically not because the scammer has your number. They use equipment that auto-dials numbers at random, and if someone answers they switch the call through to the scam operator.